# Should tags doxygen-addtogroup and doxygen-wizard be removed

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

Interested in reducing clutter and mislabelling in areas I have an interest, I wonder if these little-used tags should be removed.  (This is my first meta post - please be gentle)

[doxygen-addtogroup](/questions/tagged/doxygen-addtogroup) is an incredibly specific sub-tag and not even all of the 6 questions so tagged are relevant to the tag.

[doxygen-wizard](/questions/tagged/doxygen-wizard) is a duplicate of the [doxywizard](/questions/tagged/doxywizard) tag which itself is hardly used, but at least is correctly named.

Neither of the above have an description, and have a total of 3 followers between them.

As far as I can tell *all* the Doxygen sub-tag questions also have the Doxygen tag which is plenty.  If there is a need to 'sub class' doxygen questions it's most effectively done with a language tag for the language being documented.